# What font is used in the editor window when you are typing a new question?

Tags: support

I really like the font that is used in the editor window into which I am typing this right now - what is it?

Answer (score 2):

According to the CSS, it'll be: [Consolas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consolas), [Menlo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menlo_(typeface)), [Monaco](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monaco_(typeface)), [Lucida Console](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucida_Console#Lucida_Console), [Liberation Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberation_Mono), [DejaVu Sans Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DejaVu_Sans_Mono), [Bitstream Vera Sans Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitstream_Vera), Courier New, monospace, serif

The first one of those that's installed on your computer is the one you're seeing.

If you're on Windows Vista or 7, or have Office 2007 or Visual Studio 2010 installed, you'll have Consolas.  If you're on a recent Mac, you'll be seeing Menlo or Monaco.  You'll probably see one of the rest if you're on Linux.

`monospace` will map to whatever your browser has chosen as the monospace font.  Unless you're on a recent Ubuntu or other distro that's using newer fonts, chances are that your default monospace font is already one of those listed above.

`serif` will map to your default non-monospaced serif font.

Comment: Hmm... there must be something more to it. I definitely have Consolas installed, but when I set the font to Consolas in an editor (e.g. eclipse, Notepad++), Unicode characters don't show up properly, while in the edit box they do. What font is used to display the Unicode characters in the edit box?

Comment: @HighCommander4: That depends on the Unicode fallback of your OS & browser.

Comment: @Slaks: I see. How can I find out what that fallback is?

Comment: I don't know; sorry.

Comment: If you're using a browser with good developer tools (Safari, Chrome, Firefox + Firebug, etc), try firing it up and manually editing the active CSS for the editor element.  That's what I did to pull out the list of fonts.  Eliminate them one by one until you get a font change, and you discover the right font.